# Haskell Using monads as a sort of a global variable

Tags: haskell

I'm building a snake game and I'm using gloss graphics for the game.
I'm using G.play for initiation of the game:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
rand <- R.randomIO
let world = startWorld rand

G.play
    (displayMode world)
    backgroundColor
    stepRate
    world
    drawWorld
    handleEvent
    handleStep
```

Now the snake is basically a list of pairs of coordinates and the score is the length of the snake. However, I've added a feature of a special apple that gives you 2 points instead of 1, and only adds 1 length to the snake. But because the score is based on the snake's length I wanted to create a global variable that will count the number of times that the snake had eaten the special apple and will add that to the score. I searched the web and couldn't figure out how to actually use Monad.State to help me with this global variable.

Comment: But you already have a state: the `world`, so you probably better alter the `World` datatype and add an extra parameter to it.

Comment: Isn't the score a global variable? How does the score currently work? What about the snake's coordinates, aren't those already global? If you try to use whatever you're using already, and `State` at the same time, you'll probably end up confusing yourself even more. Use one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

You would use StateT if you would like to have access to both IO and State at the same time. State uses the exact same interface minus the extra parameter in the type constructor.

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.State
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
```

The game type is a State transformer applied to IO. This wraps State around the IO type allowing us to `lift` IO functions into the IO monad when required. Here `s` is our start state and `a` is our return state.

```
type Game s a = StateT s IO a
```

Game state is captured as a record type with the fields you want to update over time. This is where you store the snake, length, and other items in the global game state.

```
data GameState = GameState
  { _score :: Int
  , _length :: Int
  } deriving (Show)
```

To modify state we use the `modify` function from `StateT` which gets the state, applies a function over it, then sets the resulting state (`modify fn = do s <- get; put (fn s)`)

```
set :: (GameState -> GameState) -> Game GameState ()
set field = modify field

score :: (Int -> Int) -> GameState -> GameState
score fn (GameState s l) = GameState (fn s) l

len :: (Int -> Int) -> GameState -> GameState
len fn (GameState s l) = GameState s (fn l)
```

To use `IO` we must lift the function to the IO monad using `liftIO`

```
display :: Show a => a -> Game GameState ()
display = liftIO . print
```

An example of this in use follows.

```
game :: Game GameState ()
game = do s <- gets _score
          l <- gets _length
          display "initial values"
          display s
          display l
          set $ score (+2)
          set $ len (+1)
          s <- gets _score
          l <- gets _length
          display "modified values"
          display s
          display l
```

Where `runStateT game (GameState 0 0)` would print

```
"initial values"
0
0
"modified values"
2
1
((),GameState (_score = 2, _length = 1})
```

Which should fit your existing model with minor changes.